# How to import [YourProject]-Swift.h from .m files in extension target

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

My project is an objective-c project, it works fine when I import `xxxx-Swift.h` from files in the main project target. But it says error: `"xxxx-Swift.h"file not found` when I try to import it from files in today extension target.

Shouldn't this xxxx-Swift.h generated automatically? or is it not generated for all targets?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you need to create another header file for the extension target.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create any file, they are generated automatically, you just need to make sure that in your target settings, `Install Objective-C Compatibility Header` is set to ***YES***

Comment: Oops, I mean create [MODULE_NAME]_Bridging-Header.h for each target. My swift code calls some objective-c method, I not sure if it's related. Anyway, it works in my case.

Comment: Ok, in that case you need to manually create the file and set `Objective-C Bridging Header` for each target. You might even use the same file if you want.